# What is connection pooling? 

Tags: asp.net

Can somebody please explain connection pooling to me please?

I am just not understanding it by searching the internet.

Comment: this would be helpful..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360965/what-really-is-connection-pooling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please read this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx

Comment: i am not getting from there please explain me

Comment: what you are not getting? Explained well in the MSDN

Answer (score 1):

http://www.15seconds.com/issue/970531.htm

this could be also very helpful..- (:

Answer (score 1):

It is layer that handles connections. Instead of opening and handling connection from your application,
This way you say

```
gimme_connection
```

and you get the connection becuase it was allready opened or if needed it is reopened. This is usefull for databases where there are lot of "processes" who need connections on same address.